# How to design a generic class so functionality is limited based on the derived type?

Tags: oop, inheritance, encapsulation

If I have a Cat and Dog class that implement PetBase.  And they each hold an object called Owner.  And Owner holds an object called Emotion.  How would I limit accessing certain properties or functions or function parameters on the Emotion class based on whether it belongs to a Cat or Dog?  Like so:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
d.Owner.Emotion.SetFearLevel(10); // dog owners can have a fear level from 1-10 so let the user decide.
Cat c = new Cat();
c.Owner.Emotion.SetFearLevel(); // all cat owners have the same fear level so I don't want the user to be able to pass in a parameter but still be able to call SetFearLevel(). How do I enforce this?
```

In this example, I want to restrict the Cat owners from being able to pass in a parameter to SetFearLevel(), but give the Dog owners the flexibility to be as afraid as they want (ie. be able to pass in a parameter to SetFearLevel()).

What do I have to change in the design?

[***EDIT***]

It was a toss up between Jordao's and DavidFrancis's answers. In the end, I went with DavidFrancis's design due to the tree structure nature of the app.

Comment: Your tags say "encapsulation" but you describe a Pet that **has-a** owner  which **has-a** emotion which **has-a** fear which depends on the type of a thrice-composed class. What would I change? The whole model because as you have it every class needs to know details of the others.

Comment: I'll add an inheritance tag for you, but encapsulation is everywhere in inheritance.  Also, It's fine to hear the problems to the model, but I was looking for a solution.  If you know of a better way do share.

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to model, I can't offer a replacement, sorry. But I can see a OODs likely to end in disaster do show some common features and having type knowledge smeared throughout is one. Encapsulation or inheritance doesn't matter.

Comment: You should just throw an exception if someone does anything invalid. BTW: If you tell us your real life problem, we could *really* improve your design, which is probably going about everything there is good in OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetFearLevel is a different signature so you need 2 different subtypes of a base Emotion type.
Then you would need a separate owner subtype for each pet type.
Return types can usually be Covariant (ie a subtype) so each owner subtype can return the specific Emotion subtype that applies to that owner.

Comment: I tend to agree about all the subtypes - not sure if there is something clever that could be done about that...

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate the access to the functionality that you need in the classes themselves:

```
dog.setOwnerFearLevel(5);
cat.setOwnerFear();
```

Just be careful with Demeter transmogrifiers.

Comment: I've never heard of Demeter Transmogrifiers.  Thanks for educating me.  So what I recently read, is one should follow the law of Demeter with a few exceptions.  I wonder if my case would be an exception (transmogrifer) because the cat/dog need to call a couple functions and use a couple properties on the Owner class.

Answer (score 0):

Your linkages are the wrong way around.  You want to start with `owner.SetFearLevel(5)`.  Owner `owner` has to know about his/her own pet and his/her own emotions.  Hence the method can check, "Do I own a cat or a dog?" and then set it's emotion instance properly:  "I am *not* afraid dispite that parameter of 5 (because I own a cat)."  Or to put it another way, the owner references the pet, not the pet the owner.

To see this more clearly, note that your model easily allows one person to own any number of dogs and cats.  You can always create a new pet and make this hapless person the owner.  This can be useful, but it makes calculating his/her fear level rather complicated.  In a sense, it's almost impossible, because, while for any given pet you know the owner, given any owner you *don't* know the pet.  (An easily fixed problem, I admit.)

So, reference the pet (or pets--maybe use the maximum fear factor) in the Owner class and move the SetFearLevel method to the Owner class from the Emotion class, and everything should fit together nicely.

Comment: This would work if I already had an Owner.  But in this app, Pets are at the highest level.  Everything is about pets.  I don't need to know which pets an owner has.  Just who the owner is for each pet.

Comment: In that case you are making your Owner class work too hard--it's really nothing more than a name.  The fear level/emotion is a function of the pet and, logically, has nothing to do with the Owner.  Put `SetFearLevel` on Cat and Dog (as Jordao suggests) (via base class or interface) and you're set.  With somewhat emotional terms like these you have to be careful to think logically.  Try substituting classes like Car, Airplane, and Passenger and use SetTopSpeed for your method.  Same logic, but it's a bit clearer where everything goes.

Comment: Or to put it another way, you have not thought out sufficiently the nature of each of your classes.  You need to think about what an instance of each actually _is_, on its own, and how it relates to the other objects in the program, and, more importantly, how it relates to all possible future objects--the rest of the universe.  An object needs to be a complete entity all on its own, not just a bit of data with meaning only as part of some other structure.

Comment: A trivial task in deed. :)  Thanks for the helpful tips.